# Css menu resolution

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hello, I am building Joomla Template. I check my template in other resolutions regularly to see how it is looking.

My problem is the menu. I use `%` precent for width in all containers.

When I set `1024` resolution or `800X600` or zoom-in page, my horizontal menu looks like this:

```
**[ item 1 ] [ item 2 ] [ item 3 ] [ item 4 ]**
**[ item 5][ item 6][ item 7]**
**[ item 8][ item 9]**
```

But in higler resolution all work fine and show like this:

```
**[ item 1 ] [ item 2 ] [ item 3 ] [ item 4 ][ item 5 ] [ item 6 ] [ item 7 ] [ item 8 ]** ect...
```

I googled but I don't have any Idea how to fix this. Maybe I did something wrong in my code. Please check my code and if u can help me tell me what to change to fix this:

```
nav.top-meni { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0; top: 5px; width: 104%;}

   #mainlevelmainnav,#mainlevelmainnav ul {
        width: 104%;
        float: left;
        list-style: none outside none;
        line-height: 1em;
        background: transparent;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #mainlevelmainnav li {
        float: left;
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, #EBEBEC 0px, #F1F1F1 56%, #E1E1E1 62%,
            #E2E3E4 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    #mainlevelmainnav li a {
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        color: #1A1A1A;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: 15px 'droid_regular', arial, serif;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        height: 25px;
        padding: 11px 15px 3px;
        border-left: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-right: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    }

    #mainlevelmainnav li ul {
        position: absolute;
        height: auto;
        width: 11em;
        font-weight: 400;
        background: #36f;
        border: #00C 1px solid;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #mainlevelmainnav li li {
        width: 11em;
    }

    #mainlevelmainnav li ul a {
        width: 11em;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        line-height: 1em;
        font-weight: 400;
    }

    #mainlevelmainnav li a:hover {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        color: #fac825;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: 15px 'droid_regular', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        height: 25px;
        background: #1A1A1A;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
    }

    #mainlevelmainnav li:hover ul ul,#mainlevelmainnav li:hover ul ul ul,#mainlevelmainnav li.sfhover ul ul,#mainlevelmainnav li.sfhover ul ul ul
        {
        left: -999em;
    }

    #mainlevelmainnav li:hover ul,#mainlevelmainnav li li:hover ul,#mainlevelmainnav li li li:hover ul,#mainlevelmainnav li.sfhover
      #mainlevelmainnav ul li li.sfhover ul,#mainlevelmainnav li li li.sfhover ul
        {
        left: auto;
        z-index: 6000;
    }

    #mainlevelmainnav li li:hover,#mainlevelmainnav li li.sfhover {
        background: #039 url(../images/soccerball.gif) 98% 50% no-repeat;
    }

<nav class="top-meni">
     <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menu-full" /> 
</nav>
```

Comment: This is the expected outcome of what you are telling it to do.  Each individual link has a specific width determined by the text contained inside and some padding space.  When the total amount of those links is larger than the browser allows due to a resolution constriction, then the links break down to the next line, which is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thatnks for replay. It is impossible that there is no solution for this problem. I've seen a lot of sites that have the 15 items in the navigation and works great.

Comment: One way of doing it is to use display: inline-block; instead of float. Those are rendered differently, which could help you out. Also, setting a min-width on your nav container could make a difference.

Comment: @John Not saying there isn't a solution, just that your given CSS isn't going to give you what you want.  I only said so because I was under the impression that you were surprised it didn't.

Comment: @ ZorleQ when i put dislpay: inline-block; work good but now my site contaner is glued on right margin side. My container have margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly try something like this

```
#mainlevelmainnav li li, #mainlevelmainnav li ul a, #mainlevelmainnav li ul { max-width: 11em; width: 100%; }
#mainlevelmainnav,#mainlevelmainnav ul { max-width: 1600px; width: 104%; }
```

Seems like your wanting it fully responsive?

Comment: Same again but now only one item down